# Prove by induction that the product n(n+1)(n+2).....(n+r-1) of any consecutive r numbers is divisible by r!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried it by showing that true for r=0 and then assuming it to be true for r=k and trying to show it true for r=k+1. But I was not able to do that efficiently. So, please help me get a way out of it...

Comment: Please post what you did and where you faced problems.

Comment: After putting r=k+1, I got the expression as {n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)}/(k+1)! . Now I don't know how to approach further..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the binomial coefficient $\binom{n+r-1}{r}=\frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}=\frac{n(n+1)...(n+r-1)}{r!}$ is integer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expression. Also, a friendly advice: [title should NOT be the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet.